# Which is better to be use JSF's Action event or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsf

In my application i am enabling and disabling a button according to the value selected by the user from the `<h:SelectOneMenu>`. I am using a `valueChangeListener` for the same operation.My doubt is whether it is good to use `javascript` or the `valueChangeListener` for better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule #1: JavaScript can be disabled.

By the way, the `valueChangeListener` already won't be fired automatically without a *little* help of JavaScript. The `onchange="submit()"` part **is** JavaScript.

Comment: one more doubt by calling valueChangeListener request is client side or server side

Comment: The `onchange="submit()"` submits the form to the server side and Java/JSF runs at the server side, so ...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do once the value changes. With javascript, the only way to trigger a server side action is to `submit()` the form via the `onchange` attribute. This simply submits all information to the backing bean. The `valueChangeListener` on the other hand gives you more control on the server side (what element changed, what was the old value, what was the new value)

Comment: can we do this client side using javascript?

Comment: Hmmm, one of us is confused I think. Do you only want to do some client side processing when the value changes? What I mean is, when the user selects some new value, what do want that to do? Should it update a database column/other storage? Should it simply modify something on the page shown to the user?
The best solution depends on what you're trying to acomplish

Comment: I just want to enable and disable a button according to the data selected by the user, its not just on onchange enable or disable a button need to validate the data and do the enabling and disabling.